# can i send sms to the user on my database using laravel and nexmo

Tags: php, laravel, sms, vonage

I want to make sure before making payment on Nexmo if it possible to send S.M.S to my users on my database using laravel and Nexmo. Because i try doing that and what i got is a `Non White-listed Destination - rejected` error. or do i have to add all my phone numbers to nexmo database before i can use them or it is because am using the trial version.
code for sending message that gives the `Non white-listed Error`

```
$nexmo = app('Nexmo\Client');
        $nexmo->message()->send([
        'to' => \Auth::user()->phone,
        'from' => config('app.name', 'Laravel'),
        'text' => 'Text message Sent From '.config('app.name', 'Laravel').' To confrim that this is your Phone Number.'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

When initially subscribing to Nexmo, you are able to use it on up to 10 destination numbers in a demo mode until you top up your acount. To send messages to these phone numbers, you need to add them in https://dashboard.nexmo.com/.

Comment: is there programmatic way to run that. ie adding the numbers to nexmo.dashboard

Comment: I doubt so, why would you need it? It is quicker to add it manually rather than write any program to do that.

Comment: @AlexBlex If a user registers and you want to send them an sms message, it would be nice not to have to manually add their number to a white list. Does nexmo not include an api that would allow this functionality?

Comment: No. The whitelist is for testing purposes in the free demo mode. Paid clients do not have this limitation and can use it in production for any numbers.

Comment: I am facing issue after whitelisting test number unable to send SMS.getting error: status: '29',
  'error-text': 'Non White-listed Destination - rejected'

Answer (score -2):

Your phone need to add international telephone area code  before your phone
Example: 84["phone number"] => 843555555...